# Stub AWS BUCKET.presigned_post - how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stub, bucket

The AWS doc gives a minimal amount of info about stubbing RESOURCE objects but nothing on BUCKETs - anyone already solved this and able to shed some light?

Comment: Which AWS doc are you referring to, and what exactly are you trying to accomplish, and in what environment?  It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html
If I understand it correctly the ClientStubs handle the interaction between my code and the AWS cloud.  So providing there are no My/AWS interactions, I need do nothing but for any AWS function that DOES interact with the AWS cloud, I need to stub whatever cloud call is being made.  So for example I'm using the 'presigned_post' call documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/PresignedPost.html
How does this interact with AWS and what do I need to stub?

Comment: It doesn't interact with AWS.  The *pre* in presigned `POST` (and presigned URL) means the signing process (adding authentication and sometimes partial authorization information to a request) is done by an entity in possession of a set of credentials (your code) and there is no interaction with the service that happens when you do this.  The only interaction with the service is later, when the signed component is used, and that is typically done by the browser, not your code.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yep.  I'm sort of getting the idea of this and the basic premise seems to be that ALL commands might ultimately go via client/AWS interactions and Bucket, Resource etc are only wrappers around Client function.  What might be useful would be if the stubbing functions had an option for 'throw good error if AWS interaction is requested but not stubbed'.  Then I could run my code, see 'oh, this triggers client interaction X' and stub X - repeat until my stubbed testing works.